# Properly Indexing table per time on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I believe this is only me not realizing something obvious.

I currently have a table of positions for a car tracking software.
The current structure is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL, -- date being time without the hours, minutes and seconds
  `lat` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `speed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attributes` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`attributes`)),
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6),
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_0605352b480db5b3769797b9e8` (`time`),
  KEY `IDX_de42da506f977dddd80bc8e3ac` (`vehicleId`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

This table has positions from only one month, as i have a cron processes that executes once a month to remove all positions that are not from the current month.
Yet, this table got at around a million entries and queries on it became extremely slow.

I am trying to fetch all positions from a specific date and from a specific vehicle:

```sql
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE vehicleId='id here' AND date='date here';
```

But for some reason it is extremely slow.

Server is a Xeon E5-1630 v4 with 4 GB RAM and 160 GB SSD, Running Fedora 34(5.13.14-200.fc34.x86_64).
The server is running MariaDB server(10.5.12-MariaDB), Redis, Node.JS and Caddy

EDIT: Answering comments,

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM positions WHERE vehicleId='5d634444-ed56-49b2-9628-ba51182391c1' AND date='2021-09-23';
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | positions | ref  | IDX_de42da506f977dddd80bc8e3ac | IDX_de42da506f977dddd80bc8e3ac | 148     | const,const | 268  | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------+
```

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is currently at 2GB(half of my server's memory)

Comment: Could you provide result of Explain?(EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM positions WHERE vehicleId='id here' AND date='date here' )

Comment: Do you have an `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set between 1 and 3G?

Comment: Answered the questions on the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the 2G innodb buffer pool size is exceeding the normal size of commonly used data. Options to investigate before getting more ram and increasing this are:

1. as `vehicleId` appears to be a UUID, UTF8MB4 is rather wasteful on size for this. It could be converted to ascii, latin1 or something else with 1 byte per char.

```
alter table positions modify vehicleID char(36) character set ascii DEFAULT NULL
```

Ensure you change other vehicleID types in other tables otherwise joins requiring character set conversion get rather expensive (as a recent [user discovered](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26659))

Note also in 10.7.0 preview, [uuid is a new datatype](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-uuid-data-type/).

2. restrict retrieval

If you aren't using `*` you could restrict the retreival to just the fields needed. If reduced just to the index elements, this means a looking to other fields isn't needed. If `attributes` isn't need this prevents potentially other off-page lookups.

3. It looks like maybe `vehicleID,time` could be a composite primary key.

If this is the most common query, and the primary key isn't used elsewhere, this would increase the retrieval of non-secondary index elements. This would involve changing the query to use `time` ranges to most effectively use it.

Otherwise, look closer at RAM, especially ensure that MariaDB isn't swapping during query retrieval. Having buffer pool memory ending up in swap isn't useful.

Comment: Tried it up, made the changes(the columns restrictions, composite key and ASCII vehicleId) and now it's working just fine, thanks for the help!